# iPhone 7 - CPU Usage over 400%?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I've been characterizing an app I've built on an iPhone 7 to test CPU usage.

Something that strikes as odd, however, is that the max CPU usage is over 400%. Doesn't an iPhone 7 max out at 400% for its 4 cores? Any idea as to why this might be happening?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is it a simulator or a real device?

Comment: This is a real device

Comment: Use time profiler to profile your app. It will give you some more insights.

Comment: Check out for spikes on profiler, there must be some UI operation that will be leading to this.